# Does Nspec have something like Rspec's should_receive?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, bdd, nspec

I am writing an Nspec to test some file manipulation. I want to be able to intercept the call just before renaming the file, and I thought something similar to Rspec's should_receive should do. However I can't find anything like that in the Nspec documentations. Is there a equivalent in Nspec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is No.

Nspec is a BDD testing framework **without** any [Mocking/Stubbing](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) capability. If you want to use something like `should_receive` in rspec you need to use one of the many mocking frameworks in .net.

Some options:

- [Rhino Mocks](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks.ashx)
- [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/)
- [Isolator .NET](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page) (not free, but richer features)
- [JustMock](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx) (not free, but richer features)

Comment: I'd also recommend NSubstitute. Its been pretty great so far.

Comment: +1, we didn't see the need to add a dedicated mocking framework or assertion framework.  There are plenty of good ones out there -Amir (Hacker on NSpec)